# Redirecting pointers in C memory leak

Tags: c, pointers, memory-leaks

When I run valgrind on this function, it says I've definitely lost 4 bytes. I know it's because I'm redirecting the pointer x in x=y, thus losing access to the initial memory allocated in the first line. How do I fix this? What's the correct principle here? I'm just learning C, so I'm trying to get the hang of all this. Thanks!

```
int main() {
  int* x = malloc(sizeof(*x));
  int* y = malloc(sizeof(*y));
  *x = 2;
  *y = 5;
  x = y;
  *y = 6;
  *x = 4;
  printf("y = %d\n", *y);

  free(x);
  free(y);

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`x` was pointing to an int, then that address was overwritten by `x = y;` (as you expected) but the space that the previous address pointed to was not released. `x` and `y` then contain the same address and therefore both point to the same space in memory, thus your `free()` calls are both trying to free the same location.

If you don't want to leak those 4 bytes, put in `free(x);` just before `x = y;`

Comment: Great, this is what I'm looking for! I know the code isn't very useful, but it's just the concept that I'm trying to learn. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Utilize a proper swap idom by making sure you assign your value to a temporary pointer variable first so that you don't loose the pointer value that was originally assigned to `y`:

```
int* tmp = x;
x = y;
y = tmp;
```

This can be wrapped up in a `void swap(void** a, void** b)` function so that you don't have to litter your code with temporary variables.  It would look like:

```
void swap(void** a, void** b)
{
    void* tmp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = tmp;
}
```

and you would call it like `swap(&x, &y);`.

Additionally, as of right now, without your pointer swap fixed, the code

```
free(x);
free(y);
```

is an example of a double-free since the `x` and `y` variables contain the same pointer value.  Double-frees result in undefined behavior, so you don't want to-do that.  Using the proper swap idiom will prevent that.

Answer (score 3):

I'm afraid the answer is: `free` allocations when you're done with them and *don't* lose track of them before then.

Now all you have to do is learn the deep body of craft on making sure that happens...

---

As an aside you have double `free`'ed a single allocation above which is another bug.

Answer (score 2):

If you were looking to assign the value of the integer pointed to by `y` to the integer pointed to by `x`, then you probably wanted:

```
*x = *y;
```

The assignment you are doing is overwriting the *value* of `x`, rather than using its value to access the memory where your integer is stored (i.e. dereferencing it).

Incidentally, in addition to leaking with your current code, you also do a *double free* because `x` and `y` have the same value, which is also a (big) problem.

Answer (score 2):

When you assign:

```
x = y;
```

you loose the pointer (address to memory previosuly allocated) stored in `x`.
To solve it, just don't do it.  If you do that you cause **undefined behaviour** which may mean crash of your program (usually at later time) in line :

```
free(y);
```

because you are attemting to free the same memory twice.

I suspect that you wanted to assign values stored in allocated memory, not addresses, to do that you should:

```
*x = *y;
```

instead - that will solve your "lost memory" problem and the undefined behavior (double free).

Answer (score 0):

You free y twice and never free x (because x now holds the value of y).

Also, why don't you start accepting more replies? It might make people more inclined to help you.

Comment: Look carefully at what he has done. It always gets the size of the allocation right--even if the type changes later on--which makes it more robust then your suggestion.